# In Angular 8 importing Http is not work in my services?

Tags: angular, http, angular8

I have a service with crude function but when I import the Http Component I get the below error.

[image]

This one is my code

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService {

  private url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getPost() {
    return this.http.get(this.url + '?userId=6');
  }

  createPost(post){
    return this.http.post(this.url, post);
  }

  updatePost(post){
    return this.http.put(this.url + '/' + post.id, post);
  }

  deletePost(postId){
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + postId);
  }
}
```

> Angular version is Angular8

I hope can someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@angular/http api has been removed**, You are using angular 8 so use httpClient

import **HttpClientModule**  in your **AppModule** or **CoreModule**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  // import HttpClientModule module
  HttpClientModule,
 ],
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
 ],
 bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and then it's available like this in your services:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it in this way, the way you are using have been deprecated.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your Angular version?

You should probably import like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 1):

https://angular.io/guide/http

> import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

Answer (score 1):

For latest version of Angular, you need to use **HttpClient**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```